# Map/reduce regex aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection which looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51745ec04fdde5d77e4c5ed3"), "pattern" : "^a$" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51745ecb4fdde5d77e4c5ed4"), "pattern" : "^b$" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51745ece4fdde5d77e4c5ed5"), "pattern" : "^c$" }
```

I'd essentially like to see if a single input value matches any regular expression defined in the collection. I'm somewhat new to map/reduce functionality, but I'd write this in JavaScript serially like so:

```js
function matches(input, collection) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection; i++) {
        if (input.match(collection[i].pattern))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I were to write this in parallel, it'd boil down to this:

```js
function matches(input, item) {
    return input.match(item.pattern);
}
```

I'd then reduce this down to see if `true` exists in the result array.

How do I write this as a map/reduce scheme for MongoDB to find out if an input value matches any regular expression in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need map/reduce here.  It seems you can just do a simple iteration similar to this (in mongo shell):

```
> var input="a";
> db.collection.find({},{_id:0,pattern:1}).forEach(function(d) { 
   if ( input.match(d["pattern"])) 
        print (tojson(d)+" matches"); 
} )
{ "pattern" : "^a$" } matches
>
```

Comment: I'd like to perform an operation and get a simple `true` or `false` back from MongoDB. Is it possible to do so using the method you've outlined above?

Comment: replace print(tojson...) with print(true)

Comment: or put the find inside a function and return true inside if-then, return false otherwise.